# Two side layout by row

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

RMarkdown: powerpoint presentation.
I want to create two side layout: a plot and a text comment. I know how to put a layout with text commentary on the right of the plot:

````
---
title: My Presentation
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    slide_level: 3

---

### My Slide Title.

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
```{r, eval=T, echo=F}
plot(cars)
\``` # delete those tick "\" to run
:::
::: {.column}
here is my comment bout the plot blabla....
:::
::::::::::::::
````

but how put the comment below the plot?

Comment: In the chunk options, try using `fig.cap` (figure caption), e.g. `fig.cap = "comment below the plot goes here"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

````
---
title: "Slides"
author: Scipione Sarlo
date: May 21, 2019
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

# First slide

## test

- first comment
- second comment

# Second slide


:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}

```{r, eval = T, echo = F,fig.cap = "comment below the plot here it is",fig.height = 4}
plot(cars)
``` 
:::
::: {.column}

This is an example.

- first plot comment
- second plot comment

:::
````